# Navbar next e prev

Tags: javascript, html5

Bom dia,

Preciso criar um menu como este [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A ideia é que se eu estiver na palavra do autor e clicar em next ele vá para unidade 1 e se eu tiver em seção 1 e clicar em voltar ele volte para apresentação.

Hoje ele funciona mais tratei cada elemento com um if e precisava que fosse mais dinâmico porque tenho seção com 2 e seção com 5.

Comment: Faltou o seu código.

Comment: Olha se é isso que vc precisa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/336422/menu-horizontal-deslizante/336454#336454

Comment: Não neste caso o menu anda para o lado eu queria navegar entre os links